# Split single dataframe into multiple dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I'm trying to split a single dataframe into multiple dataframes as follows:

1. this is my df:

```
Date        Attributes   Symbols         value
11/12/2019  Adj Close   AALR3.SA    18.001.112
11/12/2019  Adj Close   ABCB4.SA    18.298.676
11/12/2019  Adj Close   ABEV3.SA    17.977.827
12/12/2019  Adj Close   AALR3.SA    18.211.111
12/12/2019  Adj Close   ABCB4.SA    18.653.500
12/12/2019  Adj Close   ABEV3.SA    18.005.134
13/12/2019  Adj Close   AALR3.SA    18.100.537
13/12/2019  Adj Close   ABCB4.SA    18.153.353
13/12/2019  Adj Close   ABEV3.SA    18.369.147
```

2. I'm trying to separate it into multiple dataframes to get this:

```
Date        Attributes  Symbols     value
11/12/2019  Adj Close   AALR3.SA    18.001.112
12/12/2019  Adj Close   AALR3.SA    18.211.111
13/12/2019  Adj Close   AALR3.SA    18.100.537

Date        Attributes  Symbols     value
11/12/2019  Adj Close   ABCB4.SA    18.298.676
12/12/2019  Adj Close   ABCB4.SA    18.653.500
13/12/2019  Adj Close   ABCB4.SA    18.153.353

Date        Attributes  Symbols     value
11/12/2019  Adj Close   ABEV3.SA    17.977.827
12/12/2019  Adj Close   ABEV3.SA    18.005.134
13/12/2019  Adj Close   ABEV3.SA    18.369.147
```

This is what i've tried to do:

```
for stock in df["Symbols"]:
    stock = brazilian_stocks_stack[brazilian_stocks_stack["Symbols"] == '{}'.format(stock)]
```

It didn't work because i thin that ".SA" is not being reconigzed by python.

I've also tried the following but it didn't work either.

```
for stock in df["Symbols"]:
    stock.str.replace('.SA', '', brazilian_stocks_stack["Symbols"].shape[0])= brazilian_stocks_stack[brazilian_stocks_stack["Symbols"] == '{}'.format(stock)]
```

Thanks in advance for any help you provide me.

Comment: do you really want to create additional dataframes?  Or are you just trying to group the single dataframe?

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind the splits please?

Comment: But what are exactly the splitting rules? From your example it seems that `df.iloc[::3]` would create the first sub-dataframe, `df.iloc[1::3]` would create the second etc. But you didn't explain if that's what you asked for, or just a coincidence.

Comment: I think this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).  There isn't a really need to create separate variables for parts of a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to separate it into multiple data frames to get this..

It's a bit unclear why you are trying to replace the `.SA` string, but based on the input and the expected output that you mention here is what you can do.

You can iterate over the data frames created by the grouper object which groups the df by `symbols` -

```
grouped_dfs = [i[1] for i in df.groupby("Symbols")]

for i in grouped_dfs:
    print(i)
    print(' ')
```

```
           Date Attributes   Symbols       value
11/12/2019  Adj      Close  AALR3.SA  18.001.112
12/12/2019  Adj      Close  AALR3.SA  18.211.111
13/12/2019  Adj      Close  AALR3.SA  18.100.537
 
           Date Attributes   Symbols       value
11/12/2019  Adj      Close  ABCB4.SA  18.298.676
12/12/2019  Adj      Close  ABCB4.SA  18.653.500
13/12/2019  Adj      Close  ABCB4.SA  18.153.353
 
           Date Attributes   Symbols       value
11/12/2019  Adj      Close  ABEV3.SA  17.977.827
12/12/2019  Adj      Close  ABEV3.SA  18.005.134
13/12/2019  Adj      Close  ABEV3.SA  18.369.147
```

Each element in this list is a data frame for a given `symbol`.